# Is there any way to change the popup menu color?

Tags: autocompletion, gvim, highlight

Is there any way to change the background color of the popup menu in gvim? The default background color is pink, which is a little weird to me.

[image: prompt menu]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use the following highlight groups:

- `Pmenu` – normal item
- `PmenuSel` – selected item
- `PmenuSbar` – scrollbar
- `PmenuThumb` – thumb of the scrollbar

For example to set a grey background:

```
:highlight Pmenu ctermbg=gray guibg=gray
```

For Gvim you only need the `guibg` part (`ctermbg` is used when Vim is run in a terminal), but I find it useful to always define both.

---

I didn't know this either; I used `:help i_ctrl-x` to find the help page for that key, then followed the `ins-completion` link mentioned in the entry, and searched for highlight with `/highlight` ;-)

Another way to find this information would have been to use `:help highlight-groups`, which lists all default highlight groups.

Comment: What an epic, awesome answer. Concise and absolutely love the "how to" find the info within vim, as its built-in help is quite robust. Thanks for teaching me how to fish today.

Comment: Where could we find a list of colors that we could input instead of gray?

Comment: Any way to do the same in lua (for neovim)?